# Авторазмер для Label xCode

Tags: swift, xcode, label

Я получаю строку из JSON и должен поместить её в Label, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не всегда текст помещается в Label. Подскажите, можно ли как-нибудь поставить авторазмер Label не программно?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы размеры лейбла менялись в зависимости от размера текста внутри?

Comment: Да, т.к. у меня должны храниться строки с разной длинной

Answer (score 2):

1. Выставьте констрейнты по краям контейнера, в котором находится Label. Соответственно, Label будет растягиваться на весь размер;
2. Установите у Label свойство Lines в 0. Тогда то, что не помещается в одну строку, будет переноситься на другую и, соответственно, увеличивать Label.

Answer (score 1):

Знаю только программное решение

```
extension NSAttributedString {
  func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
  }

  func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
  }
}


extension String {
  func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
  }

  func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
  }
}
```

//Реализация

```
dataLabel.text.height(withConstrainedWidth: dataLabel.bounds.width, font: dataLabel.font)
```